# MySQL Return event for specific user with an overall rank

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by, rank

How can I merge the two following queries to give me a specific users events with an overall rank?

Query 1. Returns the rank of an event based on the number of votes.

```
 SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.votes, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
 FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
 ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

Query 2. Returns events for a specific user.

```
SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.votes
FROM user_event ue
JOIN event e
ON e.guid = ue.event_uid
WHERE ue.user_uid = '123';
```

---

**Event Table**

```
guid | name | votes
-------------------
abc   event1  10
def   event2  5
ghi   event3  15
```

**User Event Table**

```
user_event_id | event_guid | user_uid 
--------------------------------------
       1          abc           123
       2          def           123 
       3          ghi           456
```

---

Combine query should return for user123

```
guid   name   votes  rank
abc | event1 | 10 |    2
def | event2 | 5  |    3
```

Or for user 456:

```
guid  name    votes   rank
ghi | event3 | 15 |    1
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with your version:

```
SELECT r.* FROM user_event ue
JOIN(
    SELECT e.guid, e.name, e.votes, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM event e, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY votes DESC
 ) AS r ON r.guid = ue.event_guid
WHERE ue.user_uid = 123
```

Comment: Yes I think this works, I shall test further though.